# Why does program not execute final printf statement?

Tags: c, for-loop, terminal, while-loop, printf

I cannot figure out why program control does not reach the third printf, right after the for loop.

Why won't the third `printf` print?

If I change the for loop to while loop, it still will not print.

Here is the program and output:

```
main()
{
    double nc;

    printf ("Why does this work, nc = %f\n", nc);
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
    {
        printf ("%.0f\n", nc);
    }
    printf ("Why does this work, nc = %f", nc);
}
```

The output is:

```
Why does this work, nc = 0.000000
test
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Try adding a newline to the last printf.

Comment: this may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1716621/748875

Comment: Out of interest: why `double` for nc? Surely an `int` would be more traditional?

Answer (score 4):

It works fine for me, how are you trying to termintate the program? The `for`-loop should end once `EOF` is detected as input by `getchar()`.

`EOF` is `Control-Z` (`^Z`) under Windows and `Control-D` (`^D`) under Linux/Unix. Once I enter this, the loop terminates and I get the final `printf()` to display its output.

As a final note (as mentioned by @DanielFisher too), add a `'\n'` at the end of your final `printf()` call as it may be required by your particular implementation or otherwise the program's behavior might be undefined (thanks to @KeithThompson and @AndreyT pointing this out in the comments):

```
 printf ("Why does this work, nc = %f\n", nc);
```

Comment: The trailing `\n` isn't just stylistic. It's implementation-defined whether a trailing `'\n'` is *required*. If it is required, failing to provide one makes the program's behavior undefined.

Comment: @KeithThompson Interesting, could you elaborate on this requirement, I hadn't heard about this before. Does it have to do with whether it causes the output buffer to be flushed?

Comment: @Levon: The language specification states in 7.19.2/2 with regard to text streams: "Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined."

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'd be happy to improve the answer or correct any errors, but It's not useful to OP, SO or me without an explanation.

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks .. I just found it and read up on it. Eliminated all references to stylistic :)

Comment: @Simon Thanks .. that's what I surmised too after KeithThompson's comment.

Comment: @Simon: On many implementations, the buffer will be properly flushed whether it's terminated with a `\n` or not. On others, it might not be. It's a good idea in any case (unless you have some specific reason not to terminate the stream with a `\n` *and* you know how your implementation behaves).

Comment: C requires the stream to be flushed, but the UB from a text file ending without a newline trumps that. On Windows, that is. POSIX requires text mode to behave identically to binary mode, which means there's no UB invoked on POSIX systems.

Answer (score 0):

[`printf`](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html) is buffered, that's why the final line *may* not be displayed.
That means a call to `printf` may not result in a direct output as the function accumulates data before putting it in the output (your terminal).

A call to [`fflush`](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#fflush) after your last printf will put everything that remains in the buffer in your terminal. Also, the buffer is flushed every time you ask for a newline.