# unusual behaviour with printf with infinite while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, printf

When I run the below program, I do not get any output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello");
    while(1)
    {

    }   
    return 0;
}
```

whereas if i edit the printf command to add a '\n' character to the end of the string, then the expected output comes. what is going on in the first code? I simply cannot understand it.

Comment: call `fflush(stdout)` btw you have infinite loop.

Comment: Output is buffered. You need either a `\n` at the end of the string to get it to print out, or use `fflush(stdout)` after your `printf` as @GrijeshChauhan suggested. There are other operations which flush the output buffer as well, such as an input function (`getchar` or `scanf`) but it's unclear from your code snippet what your loop is doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does program not execute final printf statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277796/why-does-program-not-execute-final-printf-statement)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because stdout is *line buffered*, i.e. the output is not written to the device (the terminal) until a full line has been collected.

You can call [`fflush(stdout);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) to force a flush of the buffer to the terminal. Do not try to flushing `stdin` by the way, that's not allowed.

Comment: ok but why does the code work without the infinite loop and with the same printf as above then?

Comment: When program terminates shortly after, the os would definitely flush output buffer sooner as opposed to no flush request and program being continued.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
printf("hello\n");
```

or

```
printf("hello");
fflush(stdout)
```

Comment: You should indicate that the `fflush(stdout)` occurs right after the `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf("hello\n");`

For more info see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin).